# I’m in the US on a visitor visa. Can I now apply for a volunteer visa within the country?

Tags: usa

I am a Canadian citizen who planned to stay four months traveling and surfing in the US. I am taking a one-year leave (sabbatical) from my full-time teaching position in Canada. I have met some incredible people this far and have been offered some incredible volunteer experience for a non-profit alternative outdoor school here in California.

I would love to do this for the next ten months before heading back to my position in Canada... Can I apply within the States? Is there a minimum amount of hours you need to volunteer per week?

Comment: With the new policy under the current administration, most immigrants who apply [to extend or change status are being put into deportation proceedings immediately the change of status is denied](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/changes-to-federal-policies-pave-way-for-sudden-visa-denials-deportation/). To err of the side on caution, the recommendation is nobody on visitors visa should apply to extend status unless it is a dire medical condition or something similar. When ones period of stay is up just leave and reapply from your home country.

Comment: @MusoniusRufus furthermore as a Canadian, OP almost certainly doesn't actually need a visa, so it's probably best just to travel to Canada and apply to enter the US in the new status.  This could even be less costly than a change-of-status application, depending on the person's location. The problem as I see it is...what status is appropriate?